# Taskset in linux

Tags: cpu, affinity, pinning

If we are using the taskset for setting the particular process to run on a particular core by using the process pid. I want to know that all the child processes which will generated by the pid will also run on the particular core or uses any core.

Answer (score 2):

`taskset` calls `sched_setaffinity(2)` ([here](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux/+/v2.13-pre2/schedutils/taskset.c#306)) to specify the set of CPUs a thread is eligible to run on. As `sched_setaffinity(2)`'s [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) states:

> A child created via `fork(2)` inherits its parent's CPU affinity mask.
>   The affinity mask is preserved across an `execve(2)`.

the child processes are allowed to run on the same set of CPUs as their parent.